# can't refresh webpage after changing ip on raspberry pi

Tags: php, redirect, raspberry-pi

I was working on a project to change ip of the raspberry pi from the webpage. I used php exec command to execute linux commands to change ip. well every thing is working fine. The main issue is that I can't find any way to redirect into new ip address after changing the raspberry pi ip. Can any one help me out that how I can redirect into new ip address after changing the ip of the raspberry pi

thanks in advacem

Kind Regards,
Zain

Comment: Try a PHP redirect:
`header( 'Location: http://111.111.1.1' ) ;`
This line needs to be before any output. Where 111.111.1.1 is the new IP address.

Comment: are you changing to a static address or DHCP? if you're switching to static: can you use javascript? you can set a timeout to `window.location.href = 'http://10.0.0.42';`

Comment: I am using static ip, infact I use php form to submit the request, once I submit the request, ip gets change, but i have to reopen the new tab. I tried the header('Location: http:// newip) but it dint work the reason is that once the ip is change, the webpage is no more exist on that ip. by the way what window.location.href do ??

Comment: the javascript solution will change the browser to look at the new ip address

Comment: Where can I use it, actually i tried to submit the form using the jquery, but couldnt able to redirect it. I tried that if new ip is not equal to old ip, it should redirect, but it was not accessing it. I tried it after the submit event